# How to transfer CipherText

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, encryption

I have created a CipherText using AWS Encryption SDK, now i want to send it to Rest API. Can you please tell me how to send a Ciphertext to API or how can we store a Cipher text for future use ?

I am using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Nid

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how send binary array over HTTP. You can convert it to Base64 as string then send it to your endpoint. Your endpoint should convert it from Base64 to your byte array.

```
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
byte[] newBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```